# MySQL Left Join, SELECT a field either from one or the other if null

Tags: mysql, select, null, left-join

I am trying to LEFT JOIN 2 tables. which is working out fine. But i am getting back two sets of fields named `setting_value`. iam trying to get `tblSettings`.`setting_value` only if  `tblAgencySettings`.`setting_value` is NULL. How would i go about doing this? I know i can rename the fields, then in PHP i can check the `tblAgencySettings`.`setting_value` and if NULL then grab the `tblSettings`.`setting_value` but i prefer to keep this at MySQL.

```
SELECT `tblSettings`.`id`, `tblSettings`.`setting_name`,
       `tblSettings`.`setting_value`, `tblAgencySettings`.`setting_value`
FROM `tblSettings` LEFT JOIN `tblAgencySettings` 
ON `tblSettings`.`id` = `tblAgencySettings`.`setting_id`
AND `tblAgencySettings`.`agency_id` = '1'
WHERE `tblSettings`.`changeable` = '1'
```

slight issue i just noticed. i failed to mention this. if tblAgencySettings.setting_value does have a value. but changeable is not 1 then just select tblSettings.setting_value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT `tblSettings`.`id`, `tblSettings`.`setting_name`,
       COALESCE(`tblAgencySettings`.`setting_value`, `tblSettings`.`setting_value`)
FROM `tblSettings` LEFT JOIN `tblAgencySettings` 
ON `tblSettings`.`id` = `tblAgencySettings`.`setting_id`
AND `tblAgencySettings`.`agency_id` = '1'
WHERE `tblSettings`.`changeable` = '1'
```

The COALESCE function returns the first non-NULL value you give it so this:

```
COALESCE(`tblAgencySettings`.`setting_value`, `tblSettings`.`setting_value`)
```

Will be `tblAgencySettings.setting_value` if that's not NULL and `tblSettings.setting_value` if `tblAgencySettings.setting_value` is NULL.

If `tblAgencySettings.setting_value` can also be zero and you want to ignore that as well as NULL, then you could use this instead of the COALESCE above:

```
COALESCE(
    IF(`tblAgencySettings`.`setting_value` = 0, NULL, `tblAgencySettings`.`setting_value`),
   `tblSettings`.`setting_value`
)
```

The [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) returns the second argument if the first is true and the third if the first argument is false so the above use converts zero to NULL. Or, you could go all the way to a [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) statement:

```
case
    when `tblAgencySettings`.`setting_value` = 0     then `tblSettings`.`setting_value`
    when `tblAgencySettings`.`setting_value` IS NULL then `tblSettings`.`setting_value`
    else `tblSettings`.`setting_value`
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your SQL Statement to this:

```
SELECT `tblSettings`.`id`, `tblSettings`.`setting_name`, 
   CASE WHEN `tblSettings`.`setting_value` IS NULL THEN `tblAgencySettings`.`setting_value` 
    ELSE `tblSettings`.`setting_value` END AS `setting_value` 
    FROM `tblSettings` LEFT JOIN `tblAgencySettings` 
    ON `tblSettings`.`id` = `tblAgencySettings`.`setting_id`
    AND `tblAgencySettings`.`agency_id` = '1'
    WHERE `tblSettings`.`changeable` = '1'
```

[Here's a link to MYSQL CASE Statement for your reference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)